# The Vue component only makes a POST request if you click a second time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component where I send an OTP code for verification. After verification, I store the OTP code in localStorage using Pinia and move to the next component, where I use the OTP code for other purposes.

The issue I'm encountering in this specific component is that the user enters the 4-digit OTP code in different input fields, and it receives the data as an array of 4 individual strings. Then, I convert the array into a single string and send it to the API for verification.

I've checked the code in Vue DevTools, and it works correctly on localhost. However, whenever I deploy it to the server, the conversion part doesn't work as expected.

The expected behavior is that you enter the code and click the "verify" button for verification. However, what happens on the server is that you enter the OTP code, click the "verify" button, and nothing happens. You need to enter it again and click the "verify" button a second time for it to work. Initially, I suspected that the error occurs due to simultaneous calls, so I used the watch() function to perform the conversion the moment the user types the OTP code. When the user clicks, it only makes the POST request. This approach worked fine on localhost, but I'm experiencing this unusual behavior on the server.

Could someone help me understand why this is happening and help me to fix?

```js
<template>
  <form class="otp-Form">
    <span class="mainHeading">Entrar OTP</span>
    <div>
      <p class="resendNote font-poppins">¿No recibiste el codigo?</p>
      <p v-if="countdownText === ''" class="countdownText text-brand-primary">
        Intentar de nuevo en
        <span class="font-bold text-red-600">{{ countdown }}</span> segundos
      </p>
      <button
        v-else
        class="text-brand-primary font-poppins"
        style="padding-left: 3em"
        :disabled="countdown > 0"
        @click="startTimer && reSendOTP()"
      >
        {{ countdownText }}
      </button>
    </div>
    <p class="otpSubheading">
      Hemos enviado un codigo de verificacion a tu correo electronico.
    </p>
    <p class="text-xs">
      No olvides checar su carpeta
      <span class="text-blue-800 line-clamp-1 text-center font-bold text-sm"
        >"No Deseado"</span
      >
    </p>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input
        id="otp-input1"
        v-model="otp[0]"
        required="required"
        maxlength="1"
        type="text"
        class="otp-input"
      />
      <input
        id="otp-input2"
        v-model="otp[1]"
        required="required"
        maxlength="1"
        type="text"
        class="otp-input"
      />
      <input
        id="otp-input3"
        v-model="otp[2]"
        required="required"
        maxlength="1"
        type="text"
        class="otp-input"
      />
      <input
        id="otp-input4"
        v-model="otp[3]"
        required="required"
        maxlength="1"
        type="text"
        class="otp-input"
      />
    </div>
    <button class="verifyButton bg-brand-primary" type="submit" @click="otpVerified ? moveOn() : crearCuenta()">
      Verificar
    </button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import config from "../../../environment";
import { useOtpStore } from "@/stores/otpStore";
import { useOtpCodeStore } from "@/stores/otpCodeStore";

export default {
  name: "WaitOTPMail",
  props: {
    gender: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
      required: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      otpVerified: false,
      showPassword: false,
      cellphone: "",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      toggleMailText: false,
      emailMode: true,
      cellphoneMode: false,
      countdown: 120, // 2 minutes in seconds
      countdownText: "",
      otp: ["", "", "", ""], // Initialize an array to store OTP digits
      code: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    otp: {
      handler(newOtp) {
        // Check if all OTP fields are filled
        if (newOtp.every((digit) => digit !== "")) {
          this.crearCuenta();
        }
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Start the countdown timer when the component is mounted
    this.startCountdown();
  },
  created() {
    // Start the countdown timer
    this.startCountdown();
  },

  methods: {
    toggleShowPassword() {
      this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
    },
    restrictNonNumeric(event) {
      const input = event.target;
      const value = input.value.replace(/\D/g, ""); // Remove non-numeric characters
      input.value = value; // Update the input value with the filtered numeric characters
      this.cellphone = value; // Update the Vue data property bound to v-model
    },
    emailToggled() {
      this.toggleMailText = !this.toggleMailText;

      if (this.toggleMailText) {
        this.emailMode = false;
        this.cellphoneMode = true;
      } else {
        this.emailMode = true;
        this.cellphoneMode = false;
      }
    },
    moveToRegister() {
      // Redirect to register page
      this.$router.push("/create-password");
    },
    reSendOTP() {
      this.$router.push("/newuser");
    },
    crearCuenta() {
      this.code = this.otp.join("");
      const verificarOTP = {
        check_otp: this.code,
      };
      console.log("CODE CODE CODE", verificarOTP);

      const otpCodeStore = useOtpCodeStore();
      otpCodeStore.setOtpCode(this.code); // Set the code in the store
      console.log("OTP CODE STORE: ", otpCodeStore.code);

      axios
        .post(
          `${config.activeMod.API_BASE_URL}/api/new/verify-sms-otp`,
          verificarOTP
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Verified, redirecting...", response);
          if (response.status === 202) {
            this.otpVerified = true; // OTP is verified
          } else {
            this.otpVerified = false; // OTP verification failed
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle Axios request errors here
          console.error("Axios request error: ", error);
          this.otpVerified = false; // OTP verification failed
        });
    },
    // Method to start the countdown timer
    startTimer() {
      if (this.countdown === 0) {
        // Only start the timer if the countdown is not already running
        this.countdown = 120; // Reset the countdown to 2 minutes
        this.countdownText = ""; // Clear the countdownText
        this.startCountdown(); // Start the countdown timer
      }
    },
    moveOn() {
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/create-password",
      });
    },
    startCountdown() {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.countdown > 0) {
          this.countdown--;
        } else {
          clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer when it reaches 0
          this.countdownText = "Intentar de Nuevo"; // Set the text after countdown ends
        }
      }, 1000); // Update the countdown every second (1000 milliseconds)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong but may be related with <button type="submit> you probably want to preventDefault. 
@click="
        (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          otpVerified ? moveOn() : crearCuenta();
        }
      "

Comment: @Apollo - If that were the case (and I agree it is) the real issue is, why does it behave differently in development! Oh, and by the way, in vue.js you don't need to explicitly add the `e.preventDefault()` stuff, there's a `@click.` modifier for that - and also, you don't prevent default on the submit button click, you do it on the form submit

Comment: @JaromandaX some sort of race condition maybe? if default isn't prevented, it refreshes the page. In localhost post request may be happening fast enough that moveOn() is called before that. in production it takes a while and moveOn isn't called. That's my guess of course. And you are right but I don't remember the modifier to be honest. maybe it's ```@click.prevent``` or something?

Comment: no it's `@submit.prevent` (just that, nothing else) on the `<form`

Comment: that one handles the enter key as well I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, tried @submit.prevent but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Added a lot of console.logs to see the issue, when I click the button, the function should work, but what happens is that I see my texts in console log and in miliseconds everything disappears and then that's why you need to enter the otp numbers and click the button again, because for some reason the function     crearCuenta() starts and stops immediately...